# Ubuntu 14.04 mod_rewrite issue

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04

I am using mod_rewrite to redirect urls, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/$ /login.php
```

There are several rules like this for different links on my site (I had to make individual rules because I don't want to remove .php from all URLs). The site was first launched on a CentOs server and the rewrites work just fine. I am now launching the site on an Ubuntu  14.04 and although I enabled mod_rewrite on the Ubuntu server, the rewrites don't work at all.

Following a Digital Ocean tutorial, on my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf I added the following piece of code within the tag

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

so this file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access a link that is using mod_rewrite I get a message like this on my log:

```
[Fri Sep 04 11:02:33.248187 2015] [negotiation:error] [pid 29740] [client 23.121.88.244:55114] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/login (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://104.236.103.93/
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks much!